# How to properly check if a variable is empty

Tags: bash

I have created a function to test if an app is installed or not:

```
function test_app_installed {
    local installed_app_to_search="$1"
    local installed_app_search_name
    installed_app_search_name=$(/usr/bin/mdfind "kMDItemContentType == 'com.apple.application-bundle'" |
    /usr/bin/grep -i "$installed_app_to_search")
    
    if [[ -z "$installed_app_search_name" ]]; then
        echo "false"
    fi
}
```

Thing is, this is the results I get:

```
bash-5.1$ test_app_installed Firefox
false
bash-5.1$ test_app_installed XXX
false
bash-5.1$ test_app_installed
bash-5.1$
```

Why? I mean installed_app_search_name is empty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$1` is empty, the `| /usr/bin/grep -i "$installed_app_to_search"` part is basically a no-op and `installed_app_search_name` contains the full list of applications returned by `mdfind`.

Or in other words: your test is correct, but the variable you test doesn't have the value you expect. To prevent that, you need to add something like `[[ -z $1 ]] && return` at the beginning.